# R MYSQL Write table deletes ccertain columns

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql, rsqlite

I have the following table in MySQL with the following columns

```
 tbl= ID(Integer(11)) Keyword(Varchar(55)) Estimate(DECIMAL(10,4)) 
       Error(DECIMAL(10,4))  CreateDate(DateTime)
```

Of these variables ID and CreateDate are system generated namely I need not generate the same while writing to the table from R

I am writing the following dataframe to this table

```
 DF<- Keyword   Estimate  Error
        a        23         2
        b        21         6
        c        20         5
```

I am using the following code to write this using DBWriteTable command(R SQ lite Package)

```
  dbWriteTable(conn, value = DF, name='tbl', overwrite=T, append=F, 
  field.type=list(Keyword='varchar(100)', Estimated='DECIMAL(10,4)', 
  Error='Decimal(10,4)'),row.names=FALSE)
```

Now this causes two of the columns namely the ID and Date columns to vanish in the final mysql table.

I am not sure why this is happening. I have not placed a command to drop the column I request someone to take a look and guide me.

Comment: Are you certain that the `ID` and `CreateDate` columns in fact existed before your call to `dbWriteTable`?

Comment: Just guessing, maybe change "overwrite=T, append=F," to "overwrite=F, append=T," ?

Comment: Absolutely Certain Sir. The tables are created separately. I have checked them also

Comment: @zx8754, I can try that. But it ideally should not matter.

Comment: From the manual it says: ["overwrite: a logical specifying whether to overwrite an existing table or not. Its default is FALSE."](https://rdrr.io/cran/RSQLite/man/dbWriteTable.html)

Comment: Yes. But The objective is to write the values over the earlier values. And it should not remove two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `dbWriteTable` with `overwrite=TRUE` you are telling MySQL to drop the table and recreate a new one.  In your case, it is creating a new table using the only three columns it knows about, namely what you passed to it.  One option would be to add those other two columns to your data frame:

```
DF$ID <- NA
DF$CreateDate <- NA
```

Then, make your current call.  I expect the `NA` values will map to `NULL` in MySQL, which would be consistent with the behavior of doing an `INSERT` and not specifying values for those columns.  There is a potential problem here because MySQL may not know that `ID` is an auto increment column.  So I don't like this solution very much.

The alternative, and in the spirit of what you have in mind, would be to make the following call:

```
dbWriteTable(conn, value = DF, name='tbl', overwrite=FALSE, append=TRUE, 
    field.type=list(Keyword='varchar(100)', Estimated='DECIMAL(10,4)', 
    Error='Decimal(10,4)'),row.names=FALSE)
```

Now you can just append to the already existing table.  Still, you haven't specified non `NULL` values for the `ID` and `CreateDate` columns.  So this option requires that `CreateDate` is nullable.  If `ID` is auto increment, then I expect MySQL would be able to assign an id automatically with this option.

Comment: That is one option. yes.

Comment: Thank You. In addition, I have added a dbgetquery(conn, paste("TRUNCATE tbl")). This removes the old table and adds a new one. This provides a decent compromise